# How to use findOne to compare two array object by different object id (_id)?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

//and try to compare with variants and productcode field by using findOne as below.

const store = req.body ; //and get the same collection as store collection below

//1.the first way I have tried

```
      const result = await SetPrice.findOne({
          productcode: store.productcode, 
          variants : { $elemMatch: 
          {
            $and: [
                { 
                  variantvalue : value[index]
                },
              ] 
            } 
          },
        });
```

let value = []
//and map variantvalue of store to array () and find const result in loop and doesn't response the same //collection in setPrice collection.

//2.the second way I have tried

```
      const result = await SetPrice.findOne({
          productcode: store.productcode, 
          variants : store.variants
        });
```

//How I can I use mongo aggregate to compare variants with different object id ( _id ) ?

// set price schema

```
{
    "_id": "5fe985cd187f87060489c38e",
    "productcode": "8850109152412",
    "productname": "Galaxy Tab S6",
    "variants": [
        {
            "_id": "5fe985cd187f87060489c38f",
            "variantname": "Color",
            "variantvalue": "Silver"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5fe985cd187f87060489c390",
            "variantname": "Storage",
            "variantvalue": "128GB"
        }
    ],
    "customer": [
        {
            "_id": "5fe985cd187f87060489c391",
            "level": "General",
            "price": 300
        },
        {
            "_id": "5fe985cd187f87060489c392",
            "level": "Coperate",
            "price": 280
        }
   ],
   "date": "2020-12-28T07:14:21.141Z",
   "__v": 0
},
```

// store schema

```
{
    "package": 100,
    "unit": 1,
    "_id": "5fe9fa112ffbf509d0db53c2",
    "productcode": "8850109152412",
    "productname": "Galaxy Tab S6",
    "variants": [
        {
           "_id": "5fe9fa112ffbf509d0db53c3",
           "variantname": "Color",
           "variantvalue": "Silver"
        },
        {
           "_id": "5fe9fa112ffbf509d0db53c4",
           "variantname": "Storage",
           "variantvalue": "128GB"
        }
    ],
    "total": 100,
    "date": "2020-12-28T15:30:25.036Z",
    "__v": 9
},
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use $elemMatch without $and because it matches the criteria in whole array. like this:-

```
db.collection.findOne({productcode:"specifiedCode",variants:{$elemMatch:{_id:"specified_id"}}})
```

Comment: but it has differences _id in those schema and its only has the same variantname and variantvalue sir